# SAS - Importing variable length Binary records without delimiters

Tags: file-io, sas

I have a binary data set with no delimiters and no fixed length records. I know each record contains 22 bytes of data then an unknown number of 23 byte blocks, up to 50 blocks. The problem is that it's only reading 1 line of 32767 bytes for a total of 728 obs. I'm expecting 2.7MM output obs. How can I make this read the input file to the end? I've already tried adding an "OBS=" option and "lrecl=" option to the infile line. Adding the "end=" option had no effect on the result.

```
DATA INFILE.MYDATA (drop= i);
INFILE "&Path./UGLYDATA" end=eof; 
INPUT
MY_KEY s370fPD9.
...
OCCURS s370fPD2.
@
;    
ARRAY   MyData{50}  MyData1-MyData50;
...
ARRAY   Filler{50} $ Filler1-Filler50;

DO I = 1 TO min(50,OCCURS);
INPUT
MyData{I}   s370fPD4.
...
Filler{I}   $ebcdic10.
@@
;
End;
RUN;
```

Relevant Log:

```
NOTE: 1 record was read from the infile "UGLYDATA".
      The minimum record length was 32767.
      The maximum record length was 32767.
      One or more lines were truncated.
NOTE: SAS went to a new line when INPUT statement reached past the end of a line.
NOTE: The data set INFILE.MYDATA has 728 observations and 356 variables.
NOTE: Compressing data set INFILE.MYDATA decreased size by 47.06 percent. 
      Compressed is 9 pages; un-compressed would require 17 pages.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           2.69 seconds
      user cpu time       0.02 seconds
      system cpu time     0.11 seconds
      memory              1890.40k
      OS Memory           10408.00k
      Timestamp           12/07/2021 05:17:34 PM
      Step Count                        1  Switch Count  0
      Page Faults                       3
      Page Reclaims                     1028
      Page Swaps                        0
      Voluntary Context Switches        272
      Involuntary Context Switches      1226
      Block Input Operations            309648
      Block Output Operations           2312
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to read IBM mainframe data file on a Unix machine. How did you get the file to Unix machine? Is it just a pure binary stream of bytes? What type of file was it on the mainframe?

Comment: How many bytes in the whole file? Is it ever possible for OCCURS to actually have a value that is larger than 50?  And if it does what does that mean?  That only the first 50 of the OCCURS values were written to the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the file does not consists of lines of text.  So try using RECFM=N on your INFILE statement so that SAS will not be looking for LINEFEED character (or CARRIAGE RETURN and LINEFEED combination) to mark the end of the lines.

```
INFILE "&Path./UGLYDATA" recfm=n ;
```

If you are unsure what the file contains just run a simple data step to look at the first few hundred bytes and then figure it out. If any of the bytes in a "line" are not printable characters the LIST command will include the hexcodes for the bytes under the lines when it writes to the SAS log.

```
data _null_;
  INFILE "&Path./UGLYDATA" recfm-=f lrecl=100 obs=10 ;
  input;
  list;
run;
```

Comment: Simply adding that option made it work perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Per @Tom, indeed `RECFM=N`.

Example:

Create and read back a binary file.

```
filename foo '%temp%/foo.bin' recfm=n;

data _null_;
  file foo;

  call streaminit(2021);

  filler = repeat('*', 10);

  do recnum = 1001 to 1010;
    put recnum s370fPD9. @;
    put filler $char11. @;

    occurs = rand('integer',1,26);
    put occurs s370fPD2. @; 

    do z = 0 to occurs-1;

      record = repeat(byte(rank('A')+z), 22);
      put record $ebcdic23.;

    end;

    putlog 'NOTE: ' recnum= occurs=;
  end;
  stop;
run;

data want;
  infile foo;

  * read master;
  input recnum s370fPD9. filler $char11. occurs s370fPD2.;

  * read details;
  do index = 1 to occurs;
    input content $ebcdic23.;
    output;
  end;
run;

dm 'vt want';
```

[image]

[image]